# React & TypeScript Upload File Input Error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm trying to submit a form with react & typescript but keep getting errors.

My terminal outputs this error `Type 'File | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | readonly string[] | undefined'` and if I try to upload a file the website crashes with this warning and error.

**Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.**

**Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string. at HTMLInputElement.set [as value]**

**-- EDIT --**

So after debugging for a while I have discovered that if I just pass an empty string into the value attribute then the form submits and my image / file is processed and works fine. So the issue lyes with the setting of the value attribute which mean it's this error I need to fix!
`Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string. at HTMLInputElement.set [as value]`

I have the following input component

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { styled } from "../../../stitches.config";

const Input = styled("input", {
    width: "100%",
    height: "45px",
    background: "$white",
    color: "$black",
    textIndent: "10px",
    border: "1px solid $grey",
    borderRadius: "5px",
    paddingRight: "10px",
});

interface Props extends React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
    onChange: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>;
}

export default ({ type, name, value, required, onChange }: Props) => {
    const input = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

    return (
        <Input
            type={type}
            name={name}
            value={value}
            ref={input}
            required={required}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
        />
    );
};
```

My form component looks like this

```
interface Props {
    auth: any;
}

interface FormProps {
    title: string;
    intro: string;
    content: string;
    image: File | undefined;
    published_date: string;
}

const Create = ({ auth }: Props) => {
    const { data, setData, processing, post, errors } = useForm<FormProps>({
        title: "",
        intro: "",
        content: "",
        image: undefined,
        published_date: "",
    });

    const handleFile = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        if (e.target.files) {
            setData("image", e.target.files[0]);
            console.log(data.image, " image");
        }
    };

    const onSubmit = (e: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        post("/admin/blogs/create", {
            preserveScroll: true,
        });
    };

    return (
        <Authenticated auth={auth} css={{ background: "$light" }}>
            <Container css={{ maxWidth: "1200px", py: "100px" }}>
                <Heading size="charlie">Create a post</Heading>
                <Errors errors={errors} />

                <form onSubmit={onSubmit} noValidate>
                   
                    ....

                    <Row>
                        <Label input={"image"} value={"Image"} required={true}>
                            <Input
                                type="file"
                                name="image"
                                value={data.image}
                                required={true}
                                onChange={handleFile}
                            />
                            {errors.image && (
                                <InputError error={errors.image} />
                            )}
                        </Label>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <Button
                            processing={processing}
                            type={"submit"}
                            color={"primary"}
                        >
                            Publish
                        </Button>
                    </Row>
                </form>
            </Container>
        </Authenticated>
    );
};

export default Create;
```

Comment: Does `useForm()` set the props to the component's state?

Comment: @SomaM. yes it does, the input data is stored in the `data` state. Sorry forgot to mention that I'm using inertia.js form helper https://inertiajs.com/forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the value of a file input `<input type="file" />` is read-only, it can only be an uncontrolled element, which means it does not take `value` prop. [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-file-input-tag)

In your custom input element, you may want to check the `type` before passing the `value` prop.

Comment: So simple, I didn't even realise I don't need the value on the field input! Thanks